# htaccess change .html to .php from all files inside folder

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

so i have this folder inside my site.. and i had to change all file types from html to php but inside this static html i have links to this files using html as extension... the thing is that i have php now.

is it possible to write htaccess rule for this folder so any link to .html will become .php?

www.site.com/folder1/folder2/something.php 
inside something.php i have a link to: www.site.com/folder1/folder2/somethingelse.html (but its actually .php now) and i have also hundred of files that have been change to php

i have tried lots of rules but im really noob with them, last one i have tried was

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.net
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.net/folder1/folder2/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://www.website.net/folder1/folder2/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

but it doesn't work!
please help!

UPDATE: MICHAELOKGB answer was almost ok! the only thing left to do was to set as rewritebase the actual folder: "/folder1/folder2/" and its working like a charm! thanks guys!!

Comment: Can you go into more detail than "doesn't work"? Throws a 500, redirects to the wrong page, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this. I tested it and it works.

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} folder1/folder2/(.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} folder1/folder2/(.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

Edit: Forgot to add specific folder only. If you remove **/folder1/folder2/** it will apply to whole site.

Edit2: So by response, it looks like you should change rewrite base from / (whole site) to praticular folder. Its weird, as I tested it for specific folder and it worked, but anyway:

```
RewriteBase /folder1/folder2
```

Comment: how would you do if you dont know the actual name of the file? i mean i have tons of links they could be 1.html or apple.html

Comment: oops im sorry.. i suppose $1 is kind of a wildcard

Comment: Exactly. It takes any file in that folder that had PHP extention and redirects you to html and loads the content of the original file. As normally _(the anwer above me, the edited one)_ if you went to file.php it will show you its contents _(no redirect)_, if you go to file.html, it will show you content of file.php. This code actually redirects you from file.php to file.html :) Its more SEO friendly if Google already indexed the files with php extention.

Comment: `$1` isn't the wildcard, The '.' means a single character, paired with the '*' (which is a quantifier) it means any number of characters until the last occurrence of '.php'. The $1 is the found value and the parenthesis capture that. See the basic concepts in this doc, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression should explain more and maybe you can modify in the future.

Comment: The (.*) is a "wildcard". It takes anything thats there and the $1 is whatever was matched by (.*) But the code works :)

Comment: Yes @MiChAeLoKGB, I think we just said the same thing.

Comment: still, this goes from website.com/folder1/folder2/1.html to website.com/1.php so is not working as expected :( should i set the htaccess file into folder2 or in the root of the site?

Comment: I tested it on my page and the code works. Well, depends where is your "last" .htaccess. If you have an .htaccess in folder with those files, put it there, if not, put it to closest .htaccess you have. as absically .htaccess in /folder2 overwrites one in /folder1 which overwrites one in root :)

Comment: ok i figured out running some questions down apache irc channel and the only thing left to do was to set rewritebase to /folder1/folder2/ and it started working fine! thanks for your help dude

Comment: It should work with RewriteBase / as that means whole site, and then you just specify what rule applies to what folders. But I'm glad I could help you :)